# How to add PowerBI Gateway to existing cluster using PowerShell Cmdlets?

Tags: powershell, powerbi, powerbi-gateway

I managed to install PowerBI Gateway programatically

```
Install-Module -Name DataGateway -Force -Scope AllUsers
Login-DataGatewayServiceAccount
Install-DataGateway -AcceptConditions
```

Now I am looking for a way to add this gateway to existing cluster. There is a function to remove gateway `Remove-DataGatewayClusterMember`, but for some reasons there is no function to add.

Is there anyway to add PowerBI Gateway to existing cluster using PowerShell Cmdlets or something else?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to add a cluster to an existing gateway. That cmdlet will only setup and create a new gateway cluster with the machine. Suggest you submit feedback for the Microsoft Power BI team here:

https://ideas.powerbi.com/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, added one - https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=6cd33e3e-9405-ec11-b76a-281878bd5e56

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it via Powershell as of today but you definitely do it using the UI. Here is an article that can help you.
[add-another-gateway-to-create-a-cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/data-integration/gateway/service-gateway-install#add-another-gateway-to-create-a-cluster)

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved in the October 2023 gateway updates:

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/on-premises-data-gateway-october-2023-release/